# Data visualization and icons placement

Tags: omnet++

1. I would like to change line's parameters of data visualizer (I'm not sure is the data visualizer module) like in the following image :

[image]

I tried to change lineColor parameter of all visualizer module I've found in "IntegratedCanvasVisualizer.ned" but none has effect.

2. I'd like to set icons positions and size because when I zoom out all icons are "pulled up" resulting in this :

[image]

I had a look in the source code (NetworkNodeCanvasVisualization.cc), tried to change parameter (size, distance), none has effect.

3. How to hide node's name (e.g. host[4] in first image) ?

Thanks for support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.:**

The red lines are OMNeT++'s (or, more precisely, Qtenv's) own built-in message visualizations. They are completely separate from the INET visualizers. Unfortunately, the thickness of these lines can't be changed at the moment.

Their color is determined by their (optional) DisplayStrings, see [[1](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:graphics:message-displaystrings)] and [[2](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:display-strings:message-display-strings)] for details. However, when the messages take their "line form", many of these tags, like the "shape", and "outline" are ignored.

If they have no color set in their DisplayStrings, Qtenv has an option to color the messages based on the value of their "kind" field [[3](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:messages:cmessage-basic-usage)].

If they are more in the way than they are useful, you can disable them globally in the Qtenv Preferences dialog, or you can disable message animations on a per-module basis, by setting the `builtinAnimationsAllowed` field to `false`.

**2.:**

I think you should submit this question separately in the [INET bug tracker](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/issues).

**3.:**

What @jerzy-d said. There is even a shortcut for this, `Ctrl+L`. Hiding the names of individual submodules is not possible right now.

Answer (score 1):

Ad. 3. To hide names of modules right click on the network and deselect `Show Module Names`.